# A way to forward all incoming mails to another adresss in Posfix/Zimbra

Tags: email, postfix, redirect, forwarding, zimbra

I'm looking for a way to forward all incoming mails to an external mail using postfix/zimbra, i tried "always bcc" but it forwards all mails including outgoing mails, but i'm looking for only incoming mails.

Thank you,

Comment: All incoming for account or for entire system?

Comment: Hi,
For the entire system/emails.